# Docker-Compose Apache ProxyPass To Another Container

Tags: apache, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with two containers inside, apache and my app
I'm trying to route http://localhost/myApp to my app through apache but keep getting this error

"GET /myApp/ HTTP/1.1" 500 531

Docker-compose is just two container

```
version: '3'
services:
   apache:
      image: myApache
      ports:
         - 80:80
   myApp:
      image: myApp
      ports:
         - 8081:80
```

myApache is based on httpd:2.4 with modified conf to handle ProxyPass

```
FROM httpd:2.4
ADD ./apache/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

httpd.conf is identical to the one from the base image with additional as follow

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/
   ServerName localhost
   <Directory />
      AllowOVerride None
      Require all denied
   </Dictory>

   ProxyPass /myApp/ http://myApp/
   ProxyPassReverse /myApp/ http://myApp/
</VirtualHost>
```

As far as I know, http://myApp should be able to reach the other container. I've also try http://myApp:8081 and even https://www.google.com. All are returning 500.

Comment: Do you get logs `docker logs`?

Comment: The only log from apache is
"GET /myApp/ HTTP/1.1" 500 531
even when I set logging to debug